# Can we merge the 'three.js' and 'threejs' tags?

Tags: discussion, tags, exact-duplicates

I guess these two tags are the same and one of them should be removed (preferably `threejs`):

- [three.js](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/three.js)
- [threejs](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/threejs)

Answer (score 1):

```
updating post history, 12 rows affected (pipe delimited)
updating posts, 12 rows affected  (pipe delimited)
updating PostTags associations, 7 rows affected
removing/renaming old tag, 0 rows affected
updating count for master tag, 1 rows affected
tag remapping of [three.js] and [threejs] complete!
remapping 0 synonyms
13 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
Tag Synonym threejs -> three.js was approved!
Broadcasting tag-engine reload
```

Done.

Comment: The contrarian in me was tempted to downvote this just for the hell of it.